# Pass vector as command line argument in Julia

Tags: vector, command-line, arguments, julia

Is there a way to pass a vector variable as a command line argument in Julia? In my case I have two arguments: an integer and a vector of integers. While I can easily parse the first argument, I didn't find any pleasant way to parse a vector. For now I simply set the vector to be `v = parse.(Int, ARGS[2:end])` but it is quite confusing since the items of the vector are treated as arguments. Is there a some special syntax to treat such cases?

Comment: What syntax would you like to use for the call in the command line?

Comment: Something like [1,2,3].

Comment: Could you pass your vector as a string? E.g you would call something like `julia yourscript.jl 5 "1 2 3 4 5"`. And then parse that string in your script to a vector

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your current solution is fine as it is, and in line with the way many command-line tools do things.

If you really want to pass your whole array as one command-line argument, you'll have to:

1. somehow make sure it is correctly parsed as one argument by the shell
2. parse it as an array within Julia

Both steps vary depending on the syntax you want to use.

Two examples:

**example 1**: Julia-like syntax

```sh
shell$ julia myscript.jl 42 "[1,2,3]"
i = 42
v = [1, 2, 3]
```

We can take advantage of the Julia parser being able to parse such arrays (but let's be cautious about not evaluating arbitrary julia code input by the user):

```
# First argument: an integer
i = parse(Int, ARGS[1])

# Second argument, a Vector{Int} in Julia-like format: "[1, 2, 3]"
v = let expr = Meta.parse(ARGS[2])
    @assert expr.head == :vect
    Int.(expr.args)
end

@show i
@show v
```

**Example 2:** space- or comma-separated values

```sh
shell$ julia myscript.jl 42 "1,2,3"
i = 42
v = [1, 2, 3]
```

Here, we can use [`DelimitedFiles`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/DelimitedFiles/#Delimited-Files-1) to parse the array (change the delimiter to whatever you like):

```
# First argument: an integer
i = parse(Int, ARGS[1])

# Second argument, a Vector{Int} as comma-separated values
using DelimitedFiles
v = reshape(readdlm(IOBuffer(ARGS[2]), ',', Int), :)
#                set the delimiter here ^

@show i
@show v
```